# Android Studio doesn't recognize any emulators

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio is not recognizing any external emulators (phones) connected to it.
I have tried the following mentioned things without any success:

1. Installed the device driver. (It is working fine. The device recognizes my 
   phone.)
2. Turned on USB Debugging.
3. Kill-server and then start-server commands.

I am using Android Studio for Windows.

Comment: @AndreaEbano As I already mentioned, I have tried doing that without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't installed the driver for your phone (if you use Windows). For instance, if you use Nexus or Pixel phones, you should install [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html). If you use Samsung phones, try this [link](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows).

It worked for me. If you still cannot see any of the devices, try calling 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' in the File menu in the Android Studio and restarting the system.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my problem was I was using a cable that cam with the phone that acsually would not transfer any data from\to the phone, the moment I changed the cable it worked like magic.
Just try changing a cable 1st, the PC has to recognize the device even if You have no drivers, if Your phone doesnt ask You to give permission to access from PC than the cable is just a charging cable!
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Set up a device for development (android documentation) :

> 1. On the device, open the Settings app, select Developer options, and
>      then enable USB debugging.
> 2. Set up your system to detect your device.
>
>    **For Windows**: Install a USB driver for Android Debug Bridge (adb). For an installation guide and links to OEM drivers, see the
>      [Install OEM USB Drivers](https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) document.
>
> When you connect a device running Android 4.2.2 (API level 17) or
>   higher to your computer, the system shows a dialog asking whether to
>   accept an RSA key that allows debugging through this computer. This
>   security mechanism protects user devices because it ensures that USB
>   debugging and other adb commands cannot be executed unless you're able
>   to unlock the device and acknowledge the dialog.